# SwiftUI: Read array value outside of function

Tags: arrays, sqlite, swiftui

I have loaded 2 arrays with 16 values each, after a filling an array of structs with values from a database. Here is the code.

```
    func getArrayValues() {

        var btns: [String] = []
        var translations: [String] = []
        let buttonRows = DatabaseHelper().queryDatabase(passedCategory: category)

        for each in buttonRows {
            btns.append(each.english)
            translations.append(each.indonesian)
        }
        print(btns)
        print(translations)
    }
```

The two arrays fill successfully as demonstrated by the following console output.
[image]

But I cannot read the arrays in the body view.

```
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("\(self.translation)")
                .italic()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                HStack(spacing:0) {
                    VStack {
                        Button(action: {
                            playSound(sound: "\(self.category)_audio1", type: "mp3")
                            self.translation = self.translations[0]
                        }) {
                           Text("\(self.btn1)")
                        }
```

I get the error: Value of SoundPageView has no member translations.

But when I declare the variable outside of the function it doesn't work either. To be honest I don't understanding mutating functions so I'm a bit lost. Cheers.

Comment: Where is the `getArraysValues()` function declared and where do you call it? I assume inside the `View` struct, but in the `init` or in `onAppear`?

Comment: Yes it's in .onAppear `        .onAppear {
            print("soundpage load")
            self.getArrayValues()`

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anybody is wondering, I ended up combining the two arrays into a 2d array and then returning it.

```
    func getArrayValues() -> [[String]] {
        var btns: [[String]] = [[]]
        let buttonRows = DatabaseHelper().queryDatabase(passedCategory: category)
        for each in buttonRows {
            btns.append([each.english,each.indonesian])
        }
        gotValues = true
        return btns
    }
```